# Code generator for a compiler output

Tags: compiler-construction, code-generation

I'm writing a code generator but doesn't have sufficient resources to do it. I only have the old software that have a compiler for the ST language.
What i'm trying to do is from the output o this compiler, write my code generator, maybe not the best approach, but is the best i can do.

My question is, anyone know what means the " .4asm " extension and how can i write my code generator to it?

ps: some output code:

```
.prg program1
clssid 13
var    bool rst
var    u295_initvar inizializzazioni
var    u295_cicloprova cicloprova
var    u295_elaboratest elaboratest
var    u295_salvadati salvadati
var    u295_assegnazioni assegnazioni
var    u295_allarmi allarmi
var    udint d
var    bool testen
var    u295_ricercazero ricercazero
var    u295_startmotore startmotore
var    uint count
var    u295_default default
var    dint j
var    u295_tara tara
var    uint countdelay
var    u295_blinkled blinkled
bp              0   ;"(27,2)"
stmtbeg         2   ;"(27,2)"
PSHD_IN_32      d
PSHC_01_32
add_udint       
POPD_IN_32      d

stmtbeg         3   ;"(28,2)"
PSHC_00_32
POPD_IN_32      j

stmtbeg         4   ;"(29,13)"
PSHC_TX         '1.10'
LEAO_ID         objid(__global_inst) offsetof(__global,revisioneplc)
MOVE_STRING     

stmtbeg         5   ;"(30,1)"
PSHD_IN_1       rst
not_bool        
PSHD_GI_8       ch0_in_16_23
PSHC_VV_8       byte#16#f0
and_byte        
PSHC_VV_8       byte#16#a0
eq_byte         
PSHD_IN_1       testen
or_bool         
and_bool        
jmpcn           @L0  ;to else
    stmtbeg         6   ;"(32,5)"
    PSHC_01_1
    POPD_IN_1       rst

    stmtbeg         7   ;"(33,2)"
    CALB_PN         clsid(u295_initvar) inizializzazioni

    stmtbeg         8   ;"(34,2)"
    PSHC_00_1
    POPO_IN_1       ricercazero offsetof(u295_ricercazero,start)
    CALB_PN         clsid(u295_ricercazero) ricercazero
```

...

Answer (score 0):

So what you have there is the assembly language source code generated by a compiler for the ST language. ST refers to:

> the PLC Structured Text language, as defined by the IEC 1131-3 PLC language specification (IEC, 1993). Structured Text (ST) is a high-level, block-structured, text-based language for PLCs. It is similar to Pascal, but has a number of important differences derived from its PLC application. ST programs are executed repetitively in a PLC scan, and operate on a fixed PLC memory map-I/O base. The majority of ST implementations conform to the IEC 1131-3 ST specification24. Additional information on the general characteristics of ST are provided in Appendix A.

If you have the source code program in ST then you can compile it with an ST compiler. If you have a PLC then you should have the tools required to compile this generated code into a form it will accept. If you have none of these things, this will be an uphill battle.

If this code is in a file called .4asm then this is assembly language that gets compiled into a specific PLC. if you know what PLC, you know what compiler.

The code looks Italian motorcycle. I think you need to find someone with more specialised knowledge of such things than one normally finds here.

Comment: Good point, in fact i noticed the code is a expecific assembly, we have the source code of the ST compiler, but is quite old and don't fit in our project. We don't have any kind of documentation about the compiler, only the source code and the output ( .4asm file and a lot of index files ), i was thinking to try reverse engeenering into 4asm file. But thanks for the explanation.